# How to get attribute src from iframe in iframe using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape links from the specific website but in order to succeed, I need to move over those two frames. 
As for now, by trying code above,

```
srcs.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframe"]').get_attribute('src'))
```

I am able just to scrape the src of the first frame which is just an encoded link.

So the code can access the first frame already, now I need just to go deeper. I am not sure how to do that, even the id name here is the same as a previous frame, and the XPath too.

[image]

Please help me with some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to handle inner-frame you have to switch to outer-frame:

```
# First frame
srcs.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframe"]').get_attribute('src'))
browser.switch_to.frame('iframe')
# Second frame
srcs.append(browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="iframe"]').get_attribute('src'))
```

You might need then to switch back to default content:

```
browser.switch_to.default_content()
```